# MVVM ListBox won't update with filtered Collection

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, observablecollection

```
in XAML:   
<ListBox x:Name="AllJobListBox" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="500" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllJobList}" >

in CodeBehind: 
DataContext = new LoadJobWindowViewModel();
        //ctor where ObservableCollection is instantiated and populated

in ViewModel:      //bound to textbox on View
public string SearchText {
        get {
            return searchText;
        }
        set {
            searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
        }
    }

Command:  
 public void SearchJob()
    {            
        ObservableCollection<Job> filteredJobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>(AllJobList.Where(j => j.JobName.Contains(SearchText)));
        AllJobList = filteredJobs;  
    }
```

I have been poring over blogs and posts trying to figure out what I have left out or done wrong, but can't put my finger on it.  Any assistance at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `AllJobList` raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

Your current solution is very expensive in terms of performance. You should always avoid to replace the complete source collection instance as it will force the `ListBox` to discard all containers and start a complete layout pass. Instead you want to use a `ObservableCollection` and modify it.
For this reason you should always prefer to filter and sort via the view of the collection (the `ICollectionView`). See [Microsoft Docs: Data binding overview - Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#collection-views). Manipulating the view also doesn't require to filter or sort the original collection:

```cs
ICollectionView allJobListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.AllJobList);
allJobListView.Filter = item => (item as Job).JobName.Contains(this.SearchText);
```

Since a `Binding` always uses the view of a collection as source and not the collection itself (see the link above), the `ListBox` (or the `ItemsSource` `Binding` to be precise) will automatically update when assigning a `Predicate<object>` to the `ICollectionView.Filter` property.

Comment: AllJobsList does implement OnPropertyChanged, and I do use an observableCollection, but not correctly, I presume.  I will pursue the links.  Thank you.

Comment: You should update your question and post the relevant code. Also make sure that the filter condition actually has matches.

Comment: ok, I added the snippet you supplied and it worked a charm.  Thank you so much.  I was really swimming in too much information and your post simplified it for me.  Thank you!